# Convert one level dictionary to structure of nested dictionaries

Tags: python

Given this structure of dictionary:

```
{
   'property1': 'value1',
   'property2.property3': 'value2',
   'property2.property7': 'value4',
   'property4.property5.property6': 'value3',

}
```

Need to be converted to this look:

```
{
   'property1': 'value1',
   'property2': { 
                'property3': 'value2',
                'property7': 'value4'
              },
   'property4': { 
                'property5': { 
                             'property6': 'value3'
                           }
              }
}
```

Just simple example. I'd like to see most optimized and beautiful solution. Obviously it should be function that takes first dictionary as input and outputs second one.

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this? The solution is logical and not difficult.

Comment: I tried but came up with a very difficult and dirty stuff. Going to add it in few minuts.

Comment: Post the code you've already got and maybe we can help fix it.

Comment: Gargh. I thought I'd try it, just to see. You have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, quite simple.

```
def transform(inp):
    destination = {}

    for key, value in inp.items():
        keys = key.split(".")
        d = destination
        for key in keys[:-1]:
            if key not in d:
                d[key] = {}    
            d = d[key]

        d[keys[-1]] = value

    return destination
```

To test:

```
inp = {
   'property1': 'value1',
   'property2.property3': 'value2',
   'property2.property7': 'value4',
   'property4.property5.property6': 'value3',

}

output = transform(inp)

print output

{'property1': 'value1',
 'property2': {
    'property3': 'value2',
    'property7': 'value4'
}
,'property4': {
    'property5': {
        'property6': 'value3'
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick'n'dirty solution. Seems to work, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's a simpler way to do this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def default():
    return defaultdict(default)

def convert(src):
    dest = default()
    for key, val in src.iteritems():
        cursor = dest
        path = key.split('.')
        for path_elem in path[:-1]:
            cursor = cursor[path_elem]
        cursor[path[-1]] = val
    return dest

def to_regular_dict(val):
    # optional, if you do not want to carry defaultdicts around
    if isinstance(val, defaultdict):
        return {key:to_regular_dict(val) for key, val in val.iteritems()}
    else:
        return val

src = {
   'property1': 'value1',
   'property2.property3': 'value2',
   'property2.property7': 'value4',
   'property4.property5.property6': 'value3',
}

print convert(src)
print to_regular_dict(convert(src))
```